# Spice combination(s) excluding salt, oil/butter, sugar, msg, vinegar, onion/garlic/alliums?

Tags: spices

What spice combination(s) work well for someone who (for health reasons) can't have salt, oil/butter, sugar, msg, vinegar, or alliums (onions, garlic, etc)? This person is additionally (for religions reasons) a lacto-vegetarian.

Comment: not a real answer, but wikipedia's spice/herb mixture section might be a good place to start looking:   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Herb_and_spice_mixtures

Comment: Spice combinations for *what*? There are dozens of different spices.

Comment: To extend what Aaronut said: sure, we use things like salt and oils for basic flavors a lot, but common *spices* aren't on your exclusion list. Go look at the spices section at a grocery store. With a few exceptions (garlic powder, celery salt, some premade blends...), all of those little bottles are fair game.

Answer (score 4):

There is the French *quatre épices* (four spices): pepper, cloves, nutmeg and ginger. And of course you can go crazy with the herbs: parsley, basil, rosemary, sage.
French again: *bouquet garni*, look it up [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouquet_garni).

Let me just add something about the MSG: monosodium glutamate is practically everywhere (tomatoes, cheese, seaweed, ...), not just in Chinese cuisine or soy sauce. If you **really** cannot eat MSG, your choices are going to be extremely limited. Read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glutamic_acid_%28flavor%29#Concentration_in_foods).

Broadening the field of your question, you could look into culinary traditions that, for religious or philosophical reasons, eschew those ingredients. Some Indian cuisines might help you here, but I am definitely not an expert.

Comment: I'm guessing the question is referring to a person who has forbidden **added** salt/sugar/msg/... in their diet, and though that's a bit surprising, we can't really speculate on whether it's reasonable or not. Obviously many of those things are naturally present in foods.